# Removing some tags

Tags: discussion, tag

Going through tags, I noticed there are some tags that don't make much sense.

I think we should list them here so that we can avoid using them and they'll be automatically deleted.  I'll post a community wiki answer and everyone can edit it to add and remove tags.

Comment: Please post *separate questions* for each set of tags that should be retagged / destroyed. This becomes impossible to track otherwise. Use [tag:retag-request], [tag:burninate] to categorize them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not): I fail to see what's the point of this tag, since
  there's [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin).
- [bad-nicknames](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-nicknames): I don't think anyone is going to ask question on this.
- [people](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people)
- [opinions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinions)
- [ijtihadijtihad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ijtihadijtihad)
- [love](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/love) (rename to "relationships")
- [rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules)
- [translation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)
- [knowing-god](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowing-god) this may not be used later by anyone. Alternatives are [allah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allah) [god](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god)
- [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) we already have tags [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram)
- [musical-instruments](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musical-instruments) i dont think this will ever be used alternatives are [music](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)
- [al-bara](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/al-bara) well im not sure about this
- [al-wala](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/al-wala) well im not sure about this
- [urine](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urine) ( [cleanliness](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleanliness) / [najis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/najis) will suffice? )
- [friends](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends). [relationship](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationship) should be a sufficient alternative
- [fake](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake)
- [pork](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pork). [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) should be a sufficient alternative
- [other-religions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-religions)
- [online-resources](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources)
- [day-and-time](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/day-and-time)
- [goal-of-life](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goal-of-life)
- [shia-sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-sunni). we already have tags [shia-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-islam) [sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunni)
- [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request). [citation-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-needed) is a sufficeint alternative
- [adam-and-eve](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adam-and-eve). this tag is not required and most probably may not be used in the future.
- [prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer)/[praying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/praying) remove one of these most probably praying. ('prayer' is ambiguous , use [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat) or [dua](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dua) so it becomes distinct.)
- [leaving-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaving-islam).
- [twelve](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twelve). A number? hehe... that guy must be joking
- [miracles](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miracles). not needed IMO (Ashu)
- [nature](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature). not needed IMO (Ashu)
- [advice-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice-request). [citation-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-needed)/[source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) is a sufficeint alternative
- [lease](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lease)/[leasing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leasing). Remove one or both of these. (a more general tag like [business](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) is probably sufficient)
- [asking-reason](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-reason). Im fed up of giving reasons for deleting tags

Comment: Not sure if I'd remove love, rules, or people. But others I agree about.

Comment: Love tag would better make sense as "relationships".

Comment: Well done @Ashu.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note about [shia-sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-sunni):

I think that if we edit the excerpt to

> Questions about similarities and differences between the Shia and Sunni sects of Islam

Then ought to be OK. Unfortunately, such questions spark debates due to their sensitive nature.

(One can see that the tag is full of questions from a certain suspended user who did just that--spark debates.)

---

So if you want to, keep the tag with the improved excerpt--but watch it carefully.