# Compound tags: Do we need them?

Tags: discussion, tag

I make the following definition: *compound tags* are tags of the form [x-y](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-y) where both tags [x](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x) and [y](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y) are already in use.

---

Using a [data explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/623602/list-of-tags) to generate a list of tags, and searching for those with hyphens, I found that Islam.SE has the following compound tags:

- [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) (715 Q's) is a compound of [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram).  Meta threads: 1. [How should we tidy up the halal/haram family of tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1844/17163) 2. [When to use haram and halal-haram tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1126/17163)
- [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal) (19 Q's) is a compound of [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) and [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal).  **Gone now.**
- [husband-wife](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/husband-wife) (50 Q's) is a compound of [husband](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/husband) and [wife](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wife).
- [men-women](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-women) (11 Q's) is a compound of [men](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men) and [women](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women).
- [quran-ayat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-ayat) (9 Q's) is a compound of [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) and [ayah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ayah).  **Gone now.**
- [salat-fajr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat-fajr) (4 Q's) is a compound of [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat) and [fajr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fajr).  **Gone now.**
- [shia-sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-sunni) (69 Q's) is a compound of [shiism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiism) and [sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunni).  Meta thread: [What is the "shia-sunni" tag for? Do we even need it?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/641/17163)
- [sunnah-hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunnah-hadith) (24 Q's) is a compound of [sunnah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunnah) and [hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hadith).  **Gone now.**

(I might have missed some in Arabic.)

---

This post is a question:

### Compound tags: Do we need them?

What I think:

- The compound tags [husband-wife](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/husband-wife) and [men-women](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-women) indicate *interactions* between husband and wife, and between men and women.  These might therefore be better renamed [spouse-interaction](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spouse-interaction) and [gender-interaction](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-interaction).
- The compound tag [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) is basically the union of [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram).

  - It looks like it's impractically confusing to do anything but tag anything about "halal" and/or "haram" with [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram).
  - The words "halal" and "haram" are antonyms (or close enough) that any question about "halal" will automatically be about "haram".  (There's a small number of exceptions I've seen of the form "Is X or Y more haram?")
  - "halal" also relates to "halal certification" of foods, which adds even more confusion.
- [shia-sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-sunni) seems to be used to ask about *differences* between Shia Islam and Sunni Islam.  For example:

  1. [What is the difference between a Sunni and a Shiite Mosque?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5/17163)
  2. [What are the major differences between Sunni and Shi'i prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1722/17163)
  3. [Why is the jurisprudence (fiqh) of Sunni Muslims different than Shia Muslims? (Sunni View)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2736/17163)

  In these cases, I'd say it should be broken into its components.  The word "differences" should be in the title anyway.

  There are also questions about Shia-Sunni *interactions*, e.g.:

  1. [What are the origins of Shia and Sunni division?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/967/17163)
  2. [According to which law would a Shia-Sunni couple divorce if nikah is according to Sunni law?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23309/17163)

  But it seems to get misused in several ways:

  1. For example, the OP already knows about Sunni Islam, and asks if the same thing is true in Shia Islam.  E.g. [What does the word "Shia" mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31444/17163)
  2. The OP asks about Islamic sects in general.  E.g. [Isn't it possible for Muslim Ummah to unite under one identity?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25119/17163)
  3. The OP seems to like tags starting with "Shia".  E.g. [Can I create, own & run a Dating website?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29369/17163)

  Perhaps it could be renamed [sect-interaction](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sect-interaction), like the above.
- I see no value in [quran-ayat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-ayat) and [salat-fajr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat-fajr), and think they should be broken into their components.
- I've got no idea what [sunnah-hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunnah-hadith) is about.

Comment: The sunnah-hadith tag sounds to me like bidah. It is useless at least in the way it is used. I could have imagined it be used to specify that one is looking for ahadith from sunni point of view, but this doesn't seeem to be the case. But you should know why you have used it at least?