# Do we need extra tags to cover zakat/zakah topics?

Tags: discussion, tag

We have some posts which are related to prayer like [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat), [salat-qada](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat-qada), [taraweeh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taraweeh), [tahajjud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tahajjud) etc..

For zakah or zakat, we only have [zakat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zakat) and [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah) as it seems. But when we look into fiqh books we know that zakat can be on money, gold, silver and also on livestock and property I wonder if we would need to distinguish these kinds because...
And if so would that mean that:

- We need more tags such as zakat-money , zakat-livestock etc.
- or would we need extra tags for livestock which can be combined with the zakat tag
- or any other suggestion like "keep it as it is!"

I hope for some feedback

Comment: Maybe add one for *ushr*. I am not sure if compound tags like 'zakat-livestock' are more intuitive rather than separate 'zakat' and 'livestock'.

Comment: "zakat-money" is an example of what I call a [compound tag](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2939/17163).  I'm trying to get rid of (most of) them.  We sometimes end up with questions tagged some random subset of "x" "y" "x-y" and "y-x".